# Typescript, Firebase, Cordova: Cannot find module for 'firebase'

Tags: javascript, cordova, typescript, firebase, types

I'm developing an hybrid app with Cordova and Typescript.
I need to integrate Firebase in order to read/update/save some datas from database.

My issue is about importing and using Firebase in Typescript (no framework used). And also to test it on localhost.

So, this is what I have:

`webpack.config.js`

```
module.exports = function(options) {
  return {
    [...]
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
      alias: {
        firebase: helpers.root('node_modules/firebase/firebase.js')
      }
    },
    [...]
    module: {
      rules: [
        { test: /\.ts$/, enforce: 'pre', loader: 'tslint-loader' },
        { test: /firebase\.js$/, loader: 'expose-loader?firebase' },
        { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader', exclude: '/node_modules/' },
      ]
    }
  }
};
```

`package.json`

```
{
  [...]
  "main": "src/ts/index.ts",
  "devDependencies": {
    [...]
    "typescript": "2.2.2",
    "firebase": "^4.6.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/firebase": "^2.4.32",
    [...]
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "files": [
    "./src/ts/index.ts",
    "./node_modules/@types/firebase/index.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

`src/ts/index.ts`

```
import * as firebase from "firebase";

export namespace Application {

  export function initialize() {
    const db = firebase.database();
  }

}

window.onload = function() {
  Application.initialize();
};
```

When I launch the app, it throws an error in console:

`Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_firebase__ is not a constructor`

Please, can you help me?

**UPDATE**: I've deleted unuseful lines of code and, as [@kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3433538/kevinspaceyiskeysers%c3%b6ze) told me, I've edited part of Firebase code.

Comment: check [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) first and then make an [mcve]. It does not seem to be right to call `new Firebase()`

Comment: First of all you need to read the official documentation: [Get started with firebase database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start). Then you should `import * as firebase from 'firebase'` and finally inside you component call database function to create instance ```const db = firebase.database()```

Comment: Well, I've added Firebase SDK in index.html and imported firebase module in my `index.ts`.
I've now another error: `Property 'database' does not exist on type 'FirebaseStatic'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long documentation and research and a few tries, this is a working solution:

First of all, you must have [typings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings) installed.
Open the shell and type:

1. `typings install github:typed-typings/npm-firebase`
2. `typings install firebase`
3. `npm i --save-dev firebase`

Then in `tsconfig.json`, under `files` object:

```
"files": [
  "./typings/index.d.ts"
]
```

In `src/ts/index.ts`:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase";

export namespace Application {

  export function initialize() {
    const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({ ...firebase config });
    const db = firebaseApp.database();
  }

}

window.onload = function() {
  Application.initialize();
};
```

That's all!

In this way, there won't be errors of `Cannot find module for 'firebase'`.